# PHP: newbie question - open database

Tags: php, database

I've written some simple functions for database handling like this:

```
function dbOpen($db)
{
    $username = "admin";
    $password = "pass";
    $hostname = "localhost";    
    $db = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
}

function dbClose($db)
{
    mysql_close($db);
}
```

What I want to do is get access to the variable I passed to the `dbOpen` function like:

```
dbOpen($myDB);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM my_tbl',$myDB);
```

However, for some reason this function won't initialize `$myDB`. Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: or you can simply return $db and set it as `$mydb = dbOpen()` and drop the $db param.  also you you need to select a db `mysql_select_db`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do that, you need to set up your database functions to take that variable passed as a reference. [This here explains it.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 4):

`function dbOpen($db) { ... }` won't affect the `$db` passed to it.  If you want to do that, you might try passing by reference, like `function dbOpen(&$db) { ... }`.

Better, though, would be to return the handle you just opened.  That is, instead of trying to set `$db`, just `return $db;` -- and in the code calling it, be like `$myDB = dbOpen();`.  (Note, i'm not mentioning a parameter to dbOpen -- you don't need it, since its only purpose was to be a return value.)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this might not be the exact answer you're looking for - and may be overkill - I'd like to explain how you might do this with classes in PHP. You'd do something like this:

```
<?php

class Database {

    private $db;

    function __construct() {
        $username = "admin";
        $password = "pass";
        $host = "localhost";
        $this->db = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
    }

    function close() {
        mysql_close($this->db);
    }

    function query($sql) {
        return mysql_query($sql, $this->db);
    }

}

?>
```

That `__construct()` function is called a constructor, and is run when you make a new instance of that class. Here's an example of creating and using a new instance of your database class:

```
<?php

$d = new Database();
echo $d->query('SELECT * FROM my_tbl');

?>
```

In basic terms, the arrow (`->`) after `$d`, means that you're accessing the method `query` in the object `$d` (ie. your database object). Hope this "Object-Oriented" PHP isn't too much info for a beginner - you may want to read [this swift introduction](http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-php-part-1/) to the underlying concepts.