# PHP function to display rank from highest score with timestamp of the user

Tags: php, mysql

I really need help to create a function to calculate rank from the highest score of the user. I have seen here lots of examples how to query MYSQL but I don't have enough PHP knowledge to create a function.

I have a table:

```
  PRIMARY
  blogs_id  users_id  blogs_score  blogs_rate_time
      1         23        1872     2015-09-09 05:21:51
      2         23        2146     2015-09-10 07:31:54
      3         23        2146     2015-09-10 07:32:26
      4         23        2852     2015-09-10 04:42:15 <-- same score but date older
      5         51        1793     2015-09-11 08:15:55
      6         88        2852     2015-09-11 09:33:18 <-- same score but date newer
```

I need a PHP function to display the rank of particular user in his profile. For example in the user profile page with userID 23 to display "2 place", for the user with id 88 "1 place" and etc.

I have added column `blogs_rate_time` to prevent tie ranking.

How to create a function for that?

```
  function blogsRate($user_id) {

      global $db;

      sql ="
          WHAT IS THE OPTIMIZED QUERY FOR THAT?
      ";
      $rank_query = $db->query($sql);

      HERE SUPPOSE TO BE foreach I guess?

      return ?;

  }
```

And I'm using smarty to display the result:

```
 $smarty->assign('rank_place', $users->blogsRate($userID));
```

Please help me to create working function to solve it. I would be so much thankful for **complete function but not just a mysql query or part of the function**. I'm newbie

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Do you have a working MySQL query ?

Comment: @Maximus2012, not yet. I don't have a working MySQL query because I don't know how to create a function using just query. I have a users.class where I would like to paste the function and check it.

Comment: I think those things are independent of the MySQL query. Once you have a working query, you can always find ways to get data using PHP.

Comment: why not use simply `ORDER BY blogs_rate_time, blogs_score DESC`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order your query by blogs_score and blogs_rate_time and number your rows accordingly to get the rate. I can't see your table name so I'll just call it **Ranks**, the query would look like below.

```
Set @rowNumber = 0;

Select user_id, (@rowNumber := @rowNumber + 1) As Rank From Ranks 
Order By blogs_score Desc, blogs_rate_time Asc;
```

Then your function should look like below.

```
  function blogsRate($user_id) {

      global $db;

      sql ="Set @rowNumber = 0; 
      Select user_id, (@rowNumber := @rowNumber + 1) As Rank From Ranks 
      Order By blogs_score Desc, blogs_rate_time Asc;";

      $rank_query = $db->query($sql);

      while ($row = $rank_query->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row['user_id'] == $user_id) {
            return $row['Rank'];
        }
      }

      return null; // Or something else that you can capture for not found

  }
```

However, this requires all the data to be retrieved and iterated so it'd be really expensive on resource usage. To tackle that we can run the search in database to bring only the relevant result. In order to do achieve that, first we put our query that generates the ranks in a sub query and search inside that subquery, like below.

```
Set @rowNumber = 0;

Select * From (
  Select user_id, (@rowNumber := @rowNumber + 1) As Rank From Ranks 
  Order By blogs_score Desc, blogs_rate_time Asc
) T Where user_id = $user_id Limit 1;
```

Limit 1 will only pick the first result, which should be the best rank for that user_id since I see that there could be multiple ranks for one user. In order to get only the best ranks for each user we need to add another subquery which brings only the best score and time.

```
Select * From (
  Select user_id, (@rowNumber := @rowNumber + 1) As Rank
  From (
    Select user_id, MAX(blogs_score) blogs_score, 
      MAX(blogs_rate_time) blogs_rate_time
    From Ranks
    Group By user_id
  ) G
  Order By blogs_score Desc, blogs_rate_time Desc
) T Where user_id = $user_id;
```

And your function should look like this

```
  function blogsRate($user_id) {

      global $db;

      sql ="Set @rowNumber = 0;

      Select * From (
        Select user_id, (@rowNumber := @rowNumber + 1) As Rank
        From (
          Select user_id, MAX(blogs_score) blogs_score, 
            MAX(blogs_rate_time) blogs_rate_time
          From Ranks
          Group By user_id
        ) G
        Order By blogs_score Desc, blogs_rate_time Desc
      ) T Where user_id = $user_id";

      $rank_query = $db->query($sql);

      if ($rank_query->num_rows > 0) {
          $row = $rank_query->fetch_assoc();

          return $row['Rank']; 
      }
      else return null;

  }
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49023/11

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation and function example but when I type `print_r($row['Rank']);` it returns nothing. No errors, warnings. :( And it doesn't display the rank on user's profile page. I was also testing to put actual userID into function `function blogsRate('23') {`

Comment: Hold on! Looks like my MySQL doesn't support Set @rowNumber = 0; inside single query with SELECT. I just made them separate and it works but I just need to check if the Rank is correct.

Comment: @oxyd well, sorry about that but I don't have any chance to test the code yet. I simply just typed here so it'd give you an idea. Can you tell me what's the rank you're expecting and what's the rank returned from the function?

Comment: Thanks again for your effort to make a live example. On Sqlfiddle I've changed `Order By blogs_score Desc, blogs_rate_time Asc` to `blogs_rate_time Desc` and it shows the correct result - the user 88 became on 1 place as intended. Concerning my result on my side I still have the wrong Rank place :( I have prediction it is due to MySQL version. I have MySQL 5.1.73 installed on my server and Sqlfiddle example is running on MySQL 5.6. Perhaps there is some incompatibility in version 5.1.73 and query. On my side the Rank for particular user is showing 24 place and actual place is on 9 place.

Comment: @oxyd ok, so you want to pick the oldest date first, did you change the order of the query in your function? it has very little to do with your db version than the order by.

Comment: Yes, I did. I've changed Order by on my side as well and the Rank became 24 place :) LOL (previously with Asc was 23).

Comment: Please pay attention - on Sqlfiddle example if I use userID 51 from the left table, it shows 6 place (Rank 6) but it must be on 3 place.

Comment: What makes you to think it should be on 3rd place, there is user_id 23 above that with scores 2146 and 1872 from 3rd to 5th places and then user_id 51's place is 6th with a score of 1793.

Comment: If you want each user to be ranked only once by their best score and time then you should have mentioned so. Check out this new query. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49023/11

Comment: @oxyd thanks for the tick. If the new query works for you, I'd like to edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I have made some small adjustments related to my code and seems it is working as I was expecting! I'm really sorry for not mentioning about best score for each user, I was trying to express myself in the Header but wasn't clear I guess. Anyway once again Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89422/discussion-between-oxyd-and-engin).

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = '
    SET @rank=0;
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, blogs_id, users_id, blogs_score, blogs_rate_time
        FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME
        ORDER BY blogs_score DESC,  blogs_rate_time ASC
    ) AS sub_query_table
    WHERE users_id = ' . $user_id;
```

This should do the trick. It will give you a unique result unless of course you have more than one user_id. MySQL is faster than PHP at ordering databases.

I do not know what your $db is but I guess it will return an array so you can get the value with something like:

return $rank_query[0].

Comment: Thank you for query solution but how to use this query inside function? After this query goes `$rank_query = $db->query($sql);` and what next to complete logic with return result? As I mentioned I have seen on stackoverflow many queries examples but I don't know how to make a function using the query. I would need a complete function where I can put `$userID` and display the result through smarty.

Comment: Try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363292/php-newbie-question-open-database and plug my SQL that might help you.